# Subset properties involving infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given that: $$n>3, n \in \Bbb N \;\;\text{and}\;\; A = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$$
And need to find how many subsets $B$ of $A$ have the property that: $$B \cap \{1,2\}=\emptyset$$ As well as how many subsets $B$ of $A$ for the property that: $$B \cup \{1,2\}=A$$Any help would be appreciated, especially with the terminology given.

Comment: Is the first one possibly only 1: $\emptyset$?

Comment: Perhaps the best way to interpret this question is to think about $\cup$ as the word 'or', and $\cap$ as the word 'and'. Then, for example, your first question becomes: which subsets $B\subset A$ have the property $B$ and $\{1,2\}$ have nothing in common. In this case there are many such $B$!

Comment: I'm not sure how these questions involve infinity.

Comment: @JackDavies I think I've got my head around the language now. For the first I believe the answer to be 1, $\emptyset$ and for the second question I would say it is infinite.

Comment: @Element118 Because $A$ is an infinite set of $\Bbb N$

Comment: I'm quite sure $n$ is finite, making $A$ a finite set.

Comment: $A$ is finite. $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Gareth one option for your first $B$ is $B=\{n\}$

Comment: @Element118 $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers: whole, non-negative numbers. From that I guess it isn't all the way up to infinity, my mistake.

Comment: @JackDavies But isn't, for example, $\{3\} \cap \{1,2\} = \{3\}$? And so not $\emptyset$?

Comment: @Gareth not quite. $\{1,2\}\cap\{3\}=\varnothing$ since $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$ have no common elements.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer How could it possibly be that $3\in \{1,2\}$. For all $x$, $x\in \{1,2\} \iff (x=1 \text{ or } x=2)$.

Comment: @JackDavies Oh yeah, of course. It's been a long night. So anything not containing $\{1,2\}$ and satisfies $A$

Comment: For your other 'infinity' related problem, the subtlety is that although $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which is an infinite set, each specified $n$ is finite.

Comment: @Gareth absolutely, and the next question has a similar-ish answer

Comment: I think a good answer to the first would be the power set of $n + 1$ so as to include $3$, so, $2^{n+1}$

Comment: How can you get $2^{n+1}$?  The number of elements of the power set of $A$ is $2^n$ since $|A| = n$.

Comment: @Gareth just be careful with your counting as done in the answer below. If it has been a long night, then my counting is usually the first thing to go

Comment: @GNUSupporter, It was because $n>3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And need to find how many subsets $B$ of $A$ have the property that: $$B \cap \{1,2\} = \emptyset$$

Accordingly, the set $B$ and the set $\{1,2\}$ must be disjoint; i.e., neither $1$ nor $2$ can be an element of $B$. There are $n - 2$ elements remaining, any of which can be in $B$; i.e., $B$ is a subset of $A \setminus \{1,2\}$. The number of such subsets is $2^{|A \setminus \{1,2\}|} = 2^{|\{3,\ldots,n\}|} = 2^{n - 2}$.

> As well as how many subsets $B$ of $A$ for the property that: $$B \cup \{1,2\} = A$$

Accordingly, the natural numbers between $3$ and $n$, inclusive, must be elements of $B$; i.e., $\{3,\ldots,n\} \subseteq B$. Must either $1$ or $2$ be an element of $B$? Not necessarily - but they can be without affecting the union. Consider a list of the possibilities:

- $B = \{3,\ldots,n\}$;
- $B = \{1\} \cup \{3,\ldots,n\}$;
- $B = \{2\} \cup \{3,\ldots,n\}$; or
- $B = \{1,2\} \cup \{3,\ldots,n\}$.

Therefore, there are 4 sets $B$ satisfying the condition $B \cup \{1,2\} = A$. Alternatively, $2^{|\{1,2\}|} = 2^2 = 4$.

Answer (score 3):

$B\subseteq A\land B\cap\{1,2\}=\emptyset$ means $B$ either is an empty set (because for every set $A$, $\emptyset$ is its subset and it shares no elements with $\{1,2\}$), or its elements all are also elements of $A$ with the exclusion of $1$ and $2$.

Therefore, this is equivalent to asking how many subsets of $\{3,\dotsc,n\}$ are there.

Let us count:
$$n=4:\;\;\;\;\;\;\{3,4\},$$
obviously, we can have $\emptyset,\,\{3\},\,\{4\},\{3,4\}$, therefore $4$ subsets;
$$n=5:\;\;\;\;\;\;\{3,4,5\},$$
here we can have all the subsets from the previous case, but *for each of them* it now *may or may not include* $5$, so we have $4$ of those which don't: $\emptyset,\,\{3\},\,\{4\},\{3,4\}$ and $4$ of those which do: $\{5\},\,\{3,5\},\,\{4,5\},\{3,4,5\}$, hence we have $8$ possible subsets.

You can now try to see how does this go on with $16,\,32,\,64\,\dotsc,$ so the formula for the number of subsets would be $2^{n-2}$.

You can build another way to think about it and arrive to the same formula: for each $n$ you have a set containing $n-2$ elements. Now notice you always get a subset (and you will get every possible subset) of it by removing elements from it, so the number of ways to remove elements from it also is the number of subsets. How to count the number of ways to remove elements? For each element you can assign either $0$ or $1$ which will mean either we remove that element or not. Notice that now for every way to remove elements from a set of $n-2$ elements you have a $n-2$-digit binary number (possibly with leading zeroes).
$$\{\underset{1}{3},\,\underset{0}{4},\,\underset{1}{5}\}\longrightarrow\{3,\,5\}$$
$$\{\underset{0}{3},\,\underset{0}{4},\,\underset{0}{5}\}\longrightarrow\emptyset$$
$$\{\underset{1}{3},\,\underset{1}{4},\,\underset{1}{5}\}\longrightarrow\{3,\,4,\,5\}$$
As there are $2^{n-2}$ binary numbers with $n-2$ digits in them ($b^n$ for base $b$ integer $n$ digits long in general), which you may already know, we arrive to that formula again.

For your second case please notice that the set $B$ should always contain the elements $3,\dotsc,n$ because otherwise its union with $\{1,\,2\}$ will not contain some of those elements, which are known to be in $A$, therefore it would not equal to $A$. Therefore you are only left to choose whether to include $1,\,2$ in $B$ or not. Such $B$ will always satisfy the condition, as $B\cup\{1,\,2\}$ will always contain $1,\,2$, no matter whether $B$ contained them or not. Which leaves four options: include nothing, include $1$, include $2$, include $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarity, appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome! Please notice you can support the author of an answer which you think is the best fit for your question by clicking the tick under the scoreboard, which will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since $B \cap \{1,2\}=\emptyset$, $B \subseteq A \setminus \{1,2\} = \{3,\dots,n\}$.  Therefore, any subset $B$ of $\{3,\dots,n\}$ satisfies $B \cap \{1,2\}=\emptyset$.
   $$\#\{B\subseteq A\mid B \cap \{1,2\}=\emptyset\} = 2^{n - 2}$$
2. Since $B \cup \{1,2\}=A$, we take intersection on both sides with $\{3,\dots,n\}$.  Then we have $B \cap \{3,\dots,n\} = \{3,\dots,n\}$.  In other words, $\{3,\dots,n\} \subseteq B$.  Therefore, we may choose to include elements $1,2$ or not so that $B \cup \{1,2\}=A$.
   $$\#\{B\subseteq A\mid B \cup \{1,2\}=A\} = 2^2 = 4$$

Comment: Ohhhh, I'd just arrived at thinking it might be $2^{n+1}$, but $2^{n-2}$ makes far more sense now that I consider it.

Comment: I was struggling for a satisfactory explanation to the second question. In the end, I resorted to a list of possibilities. I much prefer your approach of converting the problem with a union to one with an intersection.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment !  In fact, your (and dbanet) explanation are more detailed, and more intuitive.  I first think in this way, and then used the intersection argument to keep things concise.